# Call stack contains only external code caused by 'System.ExecutionEngineException' in System.Web.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7.5

I am getting an error I have not seen earlier and the solutions online seem to be specific to individual cases. It seems like this issue can happen for multiple reasons. I am however unable to pin point the reason for mine. Attaching a few screenshots here to show my particular issue.

I am using VS2013 for running an MVC project. All I am doing is logging in and redirecting to home page. This is the code on the Login action method:

```
IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication

//craete identity
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie.ToString());
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, vm.Email));

//sign in with Identity created
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, claimsIdentity );

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

The problem is after the redirect to the home page. The home page doesnt load when redirected to like this above. However, when called directly the home page loads without any problem.

Immediately after the redirect line is executed I get the following error
[image]

On clicking disable my code in the check box in the screen above, I get this 
[image: source not available]

After this I need to debug the application again. On running the application again after selecting [Disable my code] earlier, I get the following error.
[image]

clicking OK or Continue I  get this error
[image]

This ends up just shutting down the request and I get a page not found. 
I am running the web application using IIS. This was working code that suddenly stopped working due to the debug failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem was caused earlier up in the code. I was setting to session an object that had some properties which were getting corrupted on assignment.

Here is the error text when I checked in the quick watch window: `State = Evaluation of method COSMApps.POCO.PersonDetails.get_State requires information which is not present in the minidump you are debugging.  If you are debugging a minidump without heap, you may be able to fix this problem by collecting a new minidump`

I need to find out why this one property in my poco is failing when assigning values to it. But after taking this property out the redirect worked.

Just in case this helps anyone else, if you see an error like what I have described above, it will almost certainly be somewhere else in the code and not where the error breaks out. This is a comment I have seen in other posts as well, by people who have faced similar problems.